# How to scroll to the top using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scroll, offset

I'm trying to imitate `scrollTop` (jQuery) in vanilla JS, so on click it scrolls to an element. This works fine - unless you have already scrolled past the element. So it doesn't scroll the opposite way. Should my formula incorporate `window.pageYOffset`?

```
var moves = function(scrollz) {
    var scrollPos = document.getElementById(scrollz).offsetTop - ((document.documentElement.clientHeight - document.getElementById(scrollz).offsetHeight) / 2);

    var timerID = setInterval(function() {
        window.scrollBy(0, speed);
        if (window.pageYOffset >= scrollPos) {
            clearInterval(timerID);
        }
    }, 13);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scrollBy will scroll from "actual position" to "number of pixel defined" I think you might take a look at [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Comment: Thanks Philippe, i just set a counter starting at window.pageYOffset and incremented it at setintervals till scrollPos[above] was reached